# Is it possible to set the VertexIcon in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

Using [`Leaflet.Editable`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable), a plugin for more customized editing, it's possible to set the style of a [`L.Polyline`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline) when editing is enabled (in my case, editing a shape is enabled when you click the shape):

```
map.on('editable:enable', function (e) {
    e.layer.setStyle({color: 'DarkRed'});
});
```

Using [`Leaflet.Draw`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline), a plugin that allows more "out of the box" editing (you add a control with some settings & it does the rest) it's possible to set an icon for polyline vertices **when you first create the polyline** (and you have to do it via the control options):

```
    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    draw: {
        position: 'topleft',
        polyline: {
            icon: L.icon({
                iconUrl: '/key.png',
                iconSize: [38, 95],
            }),
            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#FF0000',
                opacity: 1,
                weight: 2
            }
        },
    },
```

The draw plugin seems to be using the icon option [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/096d404f40fd6ef1d8ca60044fdc6562bd4388a3/src/draw/handler/Draw.Polyline.js#L291-L300).

My question: **Like `layer.setStyle`, is there a way to tell a polyline to replace all of its vertices with an icon?**

Comment: more or less like this http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-custom.html  ?

Comment: No, more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mwz7pg2n/86/ (Note the custom vertex icons) but without clobbering an internal class, as I need different shapes for different types of polylines, not just 1 override for all.

Comment: make a vector of drawControl[i] and you can have full control

Comment: @HudsonPH I don't follow can you show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: I check now, and this puglin dont suport insert a vector, but you are using layer group so you can acess the events and take the current polyline i will post something for you

Answer (score 1):

create a funtion in your layergroup, you can acess the elements using event or the var, but is better for you to use the event(e) so you can take the current polynine and edit in the way you want:
[image]
[image]

```
    var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup().on('draw:editstart', function (e) {
console.log(e);
console.log(drawControl);
    drawControl.setDrawingOptions({   
        polygon: {
          icon: L.icon({
            iconUrl: '../img/logo.png',
            iconSize: [38, 95],
            iconAnchor: [22, 94],
            popupAnchor: [-3, -76]
          })  
        }
    });
});
```